# Eclipse IDE and Giraph

Tags: windows, eclipse, graph, giraph

I would like to use Eclipse IDE to create a new Giraph program. How can I include Giraph into Eclipse?. I'm new in this topic.
I used Shell Environment for running the Giraph program and text edit to write  a program. But using JAVA IDE seems the best way. How can I do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. create a maven project in eclipse
2. include apache giraph and hadoop dependencies in pom.xml as below:
   `<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.giraph/giraph-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.giraph</groupId>
      <artifactId>giraph-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>`
   `<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.20.203.0</version>
    </dependency>`
3. add the following plugins to package dependencies in a single jar with your project

   `<plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>3.6.1</version>
       <configuration>
           <!-- or whatever version you use -->
           <source>1.7</source>
           <target>1.7</target>
       </configuration>
   </plugin>`
   `<plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.5.3</version>
       <configuration>
           <descriptorRefs>
               <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
           </descriptorRefs>
       </configuration>
       <executions>
          <execution>
              <id>assemble-all</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                 <goal>single</goal>
              </goals>
          </execution>
       </executions>
    </plugin>`
4. that is all you need.